# .NET MVC: A Q when changing the value in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Thanks everyone's effort of helping me out, basically I'm facing a problem in controller below, just make it simple and easy:

```
Controller C{

       public list<model> a;
       //used in action A, if it's a searched list, then don't initialize;
       public bool searched = false;


       public ActionResult A(){
          if(searched){
             ViewBag.a = a;
          }else
          //initial the list
          a = db.model.where();
          .....
          return view()
       }

       //return a result list when people search by keywords
       public ActionResult B(string str){
          a = db.model.where(d=> d.id = str);
          search = true;
       }

    }
```

But, it turned out that the value of both a and researched never changed after B called

Did I miss some critical knowledge in .NET MVC?

Any related articles are very welcomed

Thanks

Comment: You're not putting them in the `ViewBag` when `B` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking the state will be preserved between two web requests. But when the web request ends, the entire controller is destroyed and the set information is lost unless it is stored in a persistent data store like `Session` or a database.

If I understand your code correctly, if you refactor your code slightly, you can probably achieve your searching functionality under one action, and you wouldn't need to store the data persistently.

Comment: if so, I think it does occupy both resources and time by destroy from time to time, how should I keep data in session, same like Session["list"]? (Sorry this is my 1st week on MVC and still learning)

Comment: You can try to use Session if you want, but that's not best practice when dealing with lists like this since the object needs to be serializable to be stored in Session, and it can eat memory if get a lot of results across many users. Not to mention if end user session resets losing the results. I would try to refactor the code so you don't need any persistent storage to do the filtering/searching.

Comment: you made a very good point, and this is not something barely happen, it happens everyday, in my data paging site once people search by keyword, they got a different, filtered list, then if they click 2nd page button, the list gone, only the original list without being filtered

Answer (score 1):

`Controller C` will be recreated on each request, so even though the values are updated after `B` is called, the next request for `A` will require the creation of controller `C` so a an search will be reinstantiated.

You might want to make the local variables static.

Comment: tried static, it turned out not working, any other good suggestions?

Comment: Static doesn't add them to the viewbag.  That has to be done inside B.